# How can I create two containers running the same dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that runs `["htop"]` I have a docker-compose file that runs that dockerfile but I would like to run two instances of that dockerfile, but I am having trouble doing that, each container would have its own version of htop running.

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add \
    htop

ENTRYPOINT ["htop"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  htop:
    build: .
    environment:
      TERM: "linux"
  htop_one:
    build: .
    environment:
      TERM: "linux"
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  Note that `htop` isn't a great match for Docker, for a couple of reasons: containers don't have virtual ttys that can display interactive terminal output, and they run isolated from the host in a couple of ways so you won't be able to see other processes.

Comment: @DavidMaze -  assume he's just playing around to learn more about Docker and has other plans afoot.  Why would you need two copies of htop running on the same host anyway?  pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use compose personally and am not on a PC now with docker installed to test this out but you could try this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  htop:
    build: .
    image: htop:latest
    environment:
      TERM: "linux"
  htop_one:
    image: htop:latest
    environment:
      TERM: "linux"
  depends_on:
     - htop
```

Otherwise don't use compose to build the images but build them manually and remove build: . from htop service.

i.e.  `docker build -t htop:latest .`

then use this compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  htop:
    image: htop:latest
    environment:
      TERM: "linux"
  htop2:
    image: htop:latest
    environment:
      TERM: "linux"
```

It's probably not optimal...  I think you can also just do this.

```
version: '3'
services:
  htop:
    build: .
    image: htop:latest
    environment:
      TERM: "linux"
```

Then run `docker-compose --scale htop=2 my-htop.yml`